# Solving $\int^{\pi}_{ 0.5\pi} \frac{dx}{1-\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

> Evaluate $$\int^{\pi}_{ 0.5\pi} \frac{dx}{1-\cos x}$$

This is my attempt:

$$\int^{\pi}_{  0.5\pi} \frac{dx}{1-\cos x} = \lim_{b\rightarrow0}\left(-\frac{1}{\tan(x/2)}\right)\bigg|^{\pi-b}_{0.5\pi} = lim_{b\rightarrow0^{+}}(-\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\pi-b}2)} +\frac{1}{\tan(0.25\pi)})=1$$

Which comes from $$\int\frac{dx}{1-\cos x} = \int\frac{\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}}{1-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}} = \int\frac{2dt}{2t^2} = \frac{-1}{t} +c = \frac{-1}{tan(x/2)} +c $$

and adding the limit because $tan$ is not defined at $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Is it correct?

Comment: $1-\cos x$ has a double zero at $x = \pi,$ therefore $\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \dfrac{1}{1-\cos x} dx$ does not converge as an improper integral at $x = \pi$

Comment: i didnt say it was improper....I needed the limit to plug in $\pi$ later on, since without it would not be legal

Comment: i made a mistake. double zero of $1-\cos x$ is at $x = 0.$ that is outside the interval. so there is no question of improper inetgrals.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $1+\cos x$ to get $$\begin{align}\int \frac{(1+\cos x)\,dx}{1-\cos^2 x}& = \int \frac{(1+\cos x)\,dx}{\sin^2 x} \\ \\
&= \int \csc^2 x \,dx + \int \frac{\cos x\,dx}{\sin^2 x}\\ \\ 
& = -\cot x + \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \cot x\csc x\,dx\\ \\
&=-\cot x -\csc x+C \\ \\ &= -\cot\left(\frac x2\right) + C\end{align}$$

Your evaluation of the integral are correct.

Comment: I used the trigo substitution here

Comment: What substitution did you use?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: that's how Tangent half-angle substitution works; the trigonometric function is replaced by a squared variable.

Comment: im just really not sure if applying the limit was correct but then again there was no real other way.

Comment: Note that you have to change your limits to match the substitution.

Comment: not really since I later go back to $x$

Comment: At any rate, it is difficult to guess how you arrived at your answer by not showing any intermediate steps.

Comment: I see, that aside however do you think applying the limit was correct?

Comment: I think that makes sense, @Bak.

Comment: I hope because simply plugging in $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and getting infinity didn't sound right

Comment: Recall that you are looking at $\cot(x/2)$ which corresponds to $\tan u$ with limits $\Big|_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}$ and there a problem evaluating at $\pi/2$.

Comment: So the limit is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0.5\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{1-\cos x}dx &=& \int_{0.5\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}dx\\
\end{align}
$$
Here I used
$$
\cos(2x) = 1-2\sin^2x\implies \cos(x) = 1 -2\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)
$$
using the sub $x= 2u$
$$
\int \csc^2u du = -\cot u + C
$$
thus
$$
\begin{align}
-\cot u + C &=& -\cot\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + C \\
&=& -\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x} + C\\
&=&-\csc(x) - \cot(x) + C
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{}$
\begin{align}&\overbrace{\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{\dd x}{1 - \cos\pars{x}}}}
^{\ds{\dsc{t}\ \equiv\ \dsc{\tan\pars{\frac{x}{2}}}}}\ =\
\int_{1}^{\infty}
\frac{2\,\dd t/\pars{1 + t^{2}}}{1 - \pars{1 - t^{2}}/\pars{1 + t^{2}}}
=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\dd t}{t^{2}}=\color{#66f}{\large 1}
\end{align}